# Inverse of a Polynomial Formula

Tags: polynomials

Let $P_n(x)$ be a polynomial of $n$-degree that has general form of

$$P_n(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dots+a_1x+a_0.$$

I found this formula while searching on inhomogeneous differential equations, that we can find $\frac{1}{P_n(x)}$ with

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\bigg(\frac{a_n}{a_0}x^n+\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_0}x^{n-1}+\dots+\frac{a_1}{a_0}x\bigg)^k
$$

Is this formula correct? Thanks in advance, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems that it is false even for $P = x+1$.

Comment: the formula is correct (pretty much a geometric series) when $|a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dots+a_1x| <|a_0|$ so  for $a_0 \ne 0$ there is a small disc around $0$ where it works